# Does France have addressing products similar to British AddressBase?

Tags: geocoding, ordnance-survey, address, france

In Britain people can license the Ordnance Survey's AddressBase product, which provides a list of almost all the country's addresses, with good building location  accuracy even for remote country buildings. This is obviously useful for address suggestion and geocoding applications!

Like all geodata products it's got some errors and omissions, but it's generally good (if expensive to license)

I'd like to broaden my horizon beyond just the UK. What's the best data available for France, and how good is it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Unfortunately, I think your question may be too broad for our Q&A format so I think you should edit it to perhaps focus on just the country that is most important to you first.

Comment: Just to help out - avoid Australia! The national address file (G-NAF) is fiendishly expensive - even for the tertiary education sector it's a premium charged for product.

Comment: yards is imperial - metres are metric based on the Ordnance Survey Grid.

Comment: UK (England, Scotland, Wales +Northern Ireland) OS is only GB (England, Scotland, Wales)

Comment: @PolyGeo OK. Is it bad form to submit several similar questions? If it is permitted, should there be a certain delay between posts?

Comment: I would avoid swamping by perhaps focusing this one on France for which it looks like you may have a ready to Accept answer then perhaps put out at a rate of 2-3 per day and see if answers start and continue to flow.

Comment: @PolyGeo How about now?

Comment: I tweaked your title, added a new geographic tag and voted to re-open.  I think that now serves as a good model for subsequent questions about the addressing products of other questions.  As you do each I suggest not making them exact clones with just the country name changed i.e. show that you have tried to research each new country before asking about what you may have missed.  Thanks for taking my initial advice on board.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IGN France** has a good equivalent the Ordnance Survey MasterMap  formally AddressPoint  now Address Layer 2 database.
http://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/address-layer-2.html

> based from many years of working very closely with OS addressing, it
>   is in conjunction with Royal Mail (privatised in October 2013).
>   Accuracy, it is not 100% more 92%-95% and with 28 million residential
>   and commercial properties that leaves quite a number of incorrect locations.
>   GB coverage cost with MasterMap ITN and Topolgraphy layers leads into many £10,000's)

**bdaddresse**:

http://professionnels.ign.fr/bdadresse

For European coverage **viaMichelin** have a good commercial product.

http://business.viamichelin.com/